# How to get a Null in this numeric statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

`count(distinct case when xyz is true then id else null end) as blahblah`

When the case statement returns is null it shows a 0 but I would like for it to be null. What can add or do to return a null value?

This is in SQL/BigQuery

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to wrap it in a `nullif`.

However, returning 0 on a count is the expected behavior of BigQuery as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions)

```
with _temp as (
 select 'a' as id, true as flag
 union all
 select 'b' as id, false as flag
)

select id
  , flag
  , count(distinct case when flag = true then id end) as returns_zero
  , nullif(count(distinct case when flag = true then id end), 0) as returns_null
from _temp  
group by id, flag
```

Comment: I read it as his current count returns a 0 which if you remove the nullif is what returns.  But i you add the nullif it does return a null, which is what he is asking for?

Comment: sorry, i was wrong as i misread your answer - because i was multithreading with another few questions - so i deleted my previous comments :o)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is `nullif()`:

```
nullif(count(distinct case when xyz is true then id end)) as blahblah
```

Note that the `else NULL` is not needed.

However, assuming that `id` is unique, you don't need `count(distinct)` at all.  In that case, you can replace the logic with:

```
nullif(countif(xyz is true))
```

or:

```
sum(case when xyz then 1 end)
```